# Number of automobiles produced inside the borders of the us annually last 20 years?

Tags: data-request

How many automobile units have been manufactured inside the borders of the United States annually last 20 years?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of automobiles produced inside the borders of the us annually last 20 years by manufacturer?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/number-of-automobiles-produced-inside-the-borders-of-the-us-annually-last-20-yea)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, this question might be answerable even in case the other is unanswerable.

Comment: They are effectively the same question, posted by the same person on the same date. Even if there are subtle details, it would be more useful to synthesize them into a single Q/A